# Deluge crashes when deleting a torrent

Tags: debian, linux-mint, 64bit, mate-desktop

When I go to delete a torrent, Deluge version 1.3.3 on Linux Mint LMDE 64-bit w/ MATE crashes and fails to delete the torrent. 4GB RAM, Lenovo SL400, 450GB disk space free. Happens reliably, 90% of the time. How may I collect the data to solve this?

Comment: It's highly likely to be a bug, does it happen for latest version (1.3.6) as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by install of the experimental version 1.3.6 after manually adding its repository to /etc/apt/sources.list as described at packages.debian.org/experimental/all/deluge/download